# '' has no exported member ''. angular

Tags: angular

While running the angular application I am getting the below errors

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts:32:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../client/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAdapter'.

32 import { ɵDomAdapter } from '@angular/common';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts:33:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../../../../client/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵgetDOM'.

33 import { ɵgetDOM } from '@angular/common';
```

I have tried in the internet I didn't found any solution, how to resolve these errors.

Comment: Could you post your module?

Comment: Are you using a *webpack.extra*?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I am not using any webpack.extra, If I am using where can I find that

Comment: @Jeb at the root of the project. If you aren't aware then you're not using it for sure :)

Comment: @Jeb try deleting node_modules and executing npm install again

Answer (score -1):

1 minute google, tells my that eDomAdapter is imported like that:

```
import { ɵDomAdapter } from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/1720/files

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but after adding the     `"@angular/common": "~9.1.0"` in `package.json` solved my issue.

Comment: All the symbols starting with `ɵ` are internal, and should never be exported or visible outside.
There is a problem of configuration, it can't be solved importing